# Map not open due to unknown error

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am facing unknown issue while running app. I tried a lot of times to google to find solution but no any link helped me.
What i want is to show google map while user clicks on positive button named get coordinate button
Help !

Set_Coordinate.java

```
public class Set_Coordinates extends FragmentActivity{
    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(servicesOK()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            }

        else{
            setContentView(R.layout.set_coordinates);
            }
}
    public boolean servicesOK(){
        int isAvaliable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvaliable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvaliable)){
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvaliable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }   
        else{ 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;

    }       

}
```

This is activity_map.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />
```

This is Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nabia.mutemehere"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.nabia.mutemehere.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

     <uses-permission android:name= "com.nabia.mutemehere.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>






        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Set_Location"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
            />
        <activity android:name=".Set_time"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
        <activity android:name=".Set_Phone_Setting"/>
        <activity android:name=".Set_Profile"/>
        <activity android:name=".Set_Coordinates"/>
        <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBf_4hA3cRa6qBkJuKKjEv1q4wXOnwwkT8"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my LogCat File

```
09-07 15:28:57.776: E/Zygote(12792): MountEmulatedStorage()
09-07 15:28:57.776: E/Zygote(12792): v2
09-07 15:28:57.776: I/SELinux(12792): Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9500_5.0.1_0009
09-07 15:28:57.776: I/libpersona(12792): KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10200
09-07 15:28:57.776: I/libpersona(12792): KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
09-07 15:28:57.786: E/SELinux(12792): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-07 15:28:57.786: I/art(12792): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-07 15:28:58.601: D/ResourcesManager(12792): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.nabia.mutemehere-1/base.apk
09-07 15:28:58.606: W/ResourcesManager(12792): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
09-07 15:28:58.666: V/BitmapFactory(12792): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png
09-07 15:28:58.681: V/BitmapFactory(12792): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/sym_def_app_icon.png
09-07 15:28:58.696: V/BitmapFactory(12792): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
09-07 15:28:58.701: D/Activity(12792): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
09-07 15:28:58.701: D/Activity(12792): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
09-07 15:28:58.721: D/OpenGLRenderer(12792): Render dirty regions requested: true
09-07 15:28:58.746: D/Atlas(12792): Validating map...
09-07 15:28:58.756: V/ActivityThread(12792): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{266d0a77 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3eabb11 {com.nabia.mutemehere/com.nabia.mutemehere.MainActivity}} show : true
09-07 15:28:58.886: I/OpenGLRenderer(12792): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-07 15:28:58.886: W/OpenGLRenderer(12792): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-07 15:28:58.911: D/OpenGLRenderer(12792): Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
09-07 15:28:58.911: D/OpenGLRenderer(12792): Enabling debug mode 0
09-07 15:28:58.916: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:28:58.921: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:28:58.921: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:28:58.926: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:29:04.201: I/Choreographer(12792): Skipped 278 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-07 15:29:04.506: I/Timeline(12792): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3eabb11 time:180392486
09-07 15:29:05.376: I/Choreographer(12792): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-07 15:29:05.501: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12792): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-07 15:29:06.316: I/Timeline(12792): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3eabb11 time:180394297
09-07 15:29:08.721: D/ViewRootImpl(12792): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-07 15:29:08.796: I/Timeline(12792): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.nabia.mutemehere time:180396776
09-07 15:29:09.191: D/Activity(12792): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
09-07 15:29:09.191: D/Activity(12792): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
09-07 15:29:09.236: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:29:09.241: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:29:09.241: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:29:09.241: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
09-07 15:29:09.561: V/RenderScript(12792): 0xaf807200 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
09-07 15:29:09.616: I/Timeline(12792): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@295f8a81 time:180397599
09-07 15:29:10.026: V/ActivityThread(12792): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{266d0a77 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3eabb11 {com.nabia.mutemehere/com.nabia.mutemehere.MainActivity}} show : false
09-07 15:29:13.011: D/ViewRootImpl(12792): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-07 15:29:15.871: D/ViewRootImpl(12792): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-07 15:29:16.051: V/BitmapFactory(12792): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_dialog_info.png
09-07 15:29:16.136: V/BitmapFactory(12792): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/bottom_bar.png
09-07 15:29:16.246: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 485
09-07 15:29:16.261: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 485
09-07 15:29:16.261: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 485
09-07 15:29:16.261: E/(12792): [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 485
09-07 15:29:17.361: D/ViewRootImpl(12792): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-07 15:29:17.576: I/art(12792): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Coordinates>
09-07 15:29:17.576: I/art(12792): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Coordinates>
09-07 15:29:17.581: D/AndroidRuntime(12792): Shutting down VM
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792): Process: com.nabia.mutemehere, PID: 12792
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/nabia/mutemehere/Set_Coordinates;
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Location$1$1.onClick(Set_Location.java:31)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Coordinates" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.nabia.mutemehere-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    ... 9 more
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Coordinates
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        ... 11 more
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Coordinates
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):        ... 10 more
09-07 15:29:17.581: E/AndroidRuntime(12792):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a NoClassDefFoundError, meaning there is something wrong with what you have declared and what you actually used.

Your filename `Set_Coordinate`.java differs from your class declaration

public class `Set_Coordinates` extends FragmentActivity{

Comment: Ohh i got it ! But now what should i do?

Comment: either rename the file or the class

Comment: I renamed my class from Set_Coordinates to SetCoordinates but facing same error

Comment: You have a file name Set_Coordinate.java , which defines a class named Set_Coordinate*s* and you renamed you class to SetCoordinates? What I'm trying to tell you is to rename them to have the SAME name. Either rename you filename to your classname, or the other way around, but make them have the same name

Comment: I understand what are you actually trying to say and i have already renamed both my class and file name. Now they have same name as SetCoordinate and also in Manifest file it has same name SetCoordinate. But facing same issue

Comment: what i should do now ? Help

Comment: There is another think that i want to mention here with you if i comments all code in SetCoordinates then it is called and shows empty activity. Only when i added code into it , it gives such type of error.

Comment: ok then, let's try this thing:

at com.nabia.mutemehere.Set_Location$1$1.onClick(Set_Location.java:31)

Set_Location.java file, line 31, this is where everything goes to sh1t. What is the code in that line, what are you executing?